# Shading lasting only a second

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to set a green shade on a component of a model that only lasts for a second. I was trying to use $timeout but that only delays the shading. It doesn't actually stop the shading. I googled it of course, but only came up with a bunch of stuff dealing with the $timeout function stated above. Hooray. Any ideas? Here's the code for what I tried. It doesn't work, but . . .

```
 $timeout(function(){
     tml3dRenderer.setColor($scope.currentSelection, Right_COLOR); //turn the object green
 }, 500)  //.5 second timer on green shading
```

Comment: You'd have to add another timeout to turn the element back to its original color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the color immediately, and then change it back in the timer:

```
tml3dRenderer.setColor($scope.currentSelection, Right_COLOR);      // to green, immediately
$timeout(function(){
  tml3dRenderer.setColor($scope.currentSelection, Original_COLOR); // back to original, delayed
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot